# Can I run 90 feet of 6/3 NM-B, carrying 220 Volts/50 Amperes, in schedule 80 PVC?

Tags: wiring

I am adding a 50amp, 220v receptacle to my garage.  I am mounting 6/3 wire with ground (NM-B).  The run is approximately 90 feet long and it passes through one wall.  It will be out of harms way at the top of the wall at the ceiling.  For aesthetics I propose to put it in schedule 80 PVC.  Is this permitted?  For a run that long do I need junction boxes along the way?  It involves four 90 degree turns.

Comment: And you haven't told us the good stuff.. what's the extra power for?  (Big table saw, welder, vertical mill?  Some awesome new garage toy we hope.    :^)

Comment: Instead of all the hastles anticipated by all just run the 6/3 through the conduit as you are putting it together, eliminating all the troubles! Are you using this to add some heat to your garage or other important use ;) lol lol we are all anticipating some kind of reason for running an expensive circuit.

Answer (score 3):

Your voltage drop is less than 4V so that is good. With 4 90's it would be legal to do it without junction boxes(360 max - then boxes are required). Soap the wire when pulling it will go much easier. We used to use Dawn dish soap but they also make "pull soap" that wont dry out and get sticky like Dawn.

Comment: Is a pull-box at each 90 enough or do you need a large junction box in line somewhere?

Comment: You do not need any pull boxes with only 4 90's you can go from your panel directly to the box on the end. If you have more than 4 90's it would be required to add pull boxes (or an LB conduit body instead of a 90).

Comment: They make PVC pipe and hardware specifically for conduit, or you could use EMT and not need to pull a ground.  NM in conduit doesn't make sense, the sheath is useless and may force a wire derate, is illegal in wet areas, and is hard to pull.  Run THHN stranded (individual wires). With four 90 bends it is going to be a miserable conduit pull. I prefer to fit at corners either a junction box or conduit body (which has a removable cap for access to pull), and no more than a single 90 between.  That makes pulls so easy I can often just push the wire.

Comment: And more than once I've run into a 90 bend I now need to turn into a Tee.  That's a job because the pipe radius is bigger than the box, so at least the last foot of conduit on each leg needs to be replaced, rebent etc.